# PHP query com resposta de outra query

Tags: php, mysql, query

Executo uma query que me retorna uma lista de IDs. Com cada ID desta lista quero fazer um insert em uma segunda tabela.

Meu código:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("Erro ao conectar na base de dados MySQL!");
$query = "select id from country";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $var = $row["id"];
    mysqli_query($db, "insert into testando (numero) values ('$var')");

} 

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

Quando executo, apenas 1 registro é inserido no banco. Se executo uma segunda vez, nada acontece. Onde estou errando??

Comment: O erro pode estar sendo causado pela sua estrutura do banco, por exemplo, se numero for alguma pk, não mostra nem um erro na tela?

Comment: Não...sem erros em tela. E "numero" não é uma PK na tabela "testando".